# Are computeIfPresent and computeIfAbsent when used one after another considered as atomic operations?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, atomic, concurrenthashmap

Given the following class, if multiple threads are executing the `testComputeIfPresentAndAbsent` method simultaneously, is the code thread safe? :

```
public class ComputeIfPresentAndAbsent {

    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, MyPojo> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private void testComputeIfPresentAndAbsent(String key, MyPojo newObj) {
        map.computeIfPresent(key, (k, existingObj) -> aggregate(existingObj, newObj));//Line 1
        map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> newObj);//Line 2
    }

    private MyPojo aggregate(MyPojo existingObj, MyPojo newPojo) {
        newPojo.getField1().add(existingObj.getField1());
        newPojo.getField2().add(existingObj.getField2());
        return newPojo;
    }

    class MyPojo {

        private BigDecimal field1;
        private BigDecimal field2;

        public BigDecimal getField1() {
            return field1;
        }

        public void setField1(BigDecimal field1) {
            this.field1 = field1;
        }

        public BigDecimal getField2() {
            return field2;
        }

        public void setField2(BigDecimal field2) {
            this.field2 = field2;
        }

    }
}
```

In other words, is calling `computeIfPresent` and `computeIfAbsent` one after another going to be an atomic operation or Is there a possibility of a race condition still occurring in this scenario?

If I had to simplify the question, consider the following chronology of events :

1. Thread A executes Line 1 (`computeIfPresent`) for key 1. Since key 1 is not present, `aggregate` function is not called on key 1 by Thread A.
2. Thread A executes Line 2  (`computeIfAbsent`) for key 1 and is in the process of adding the object against key 1. At the same time, Thread B comes in and executes line 1 (`computeIfPresent`) for key 1.

**Question:** Will thread B wait at Line 1 until thread A finishes executing Line 2 (`computeIfAbsent`) and only then execute the `aggregate` function? Or will Thread B immediately move on to Line 2 without waiting at Line 1? (Assuming both threads operate on the same key)

My understanding is that Thread B will not wait at Line 1 while Thread A is executing Line 2 for the same key. Is this understanding correct? If yes, then this code is not thread safe as multiple threads can miss calling the aggregate method altogether. Even if I was able to prove this theory through some sample program calling the `testComputeIfPresentAndAbsent` method in 10000 threads, I am primarily interested in understanding why this code is not thread safe and whether my understanding is correct?

Comment: Why you need atomicity here?

Comment: @RavindraRanwala I explained this in the last paragraph of my question. "My understanding is that it is possible that multiple threads miss calling the aggregate method all together resulting in an incorrect aggregate value against the same key at the end of the execution". Is this possible?

Comment: Anyway, the question and the intention is not clear to me.

Comment: The question is, is the code thread safe. At the end of the execution, is it possible to see incorrect aggregate values against a particular key in the `Map`? The aggregate function passed to `computeIfAbsent` is aggregating the numeric fields against a particular key in the Map.The way the code is written, is it possible that the final value for field1 and field2 for `MyPojo` corresponding to a particular key is inconsistent?

Comment: what is the criteria of correct aggregate  value?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov The sum of `field1` needs to be correct for a given key. Assume that 1 million threads each call  `testComputeIfPresentAndAbsent` method, passing it the key as `key1` and a new `MyPojo` object with `field1` set to `1`. At the end of the execution of all the threads, the value of `field1` for the `MyPojo` object against `key1` should be 1 million.

Comment: Suppose five threads arrive at `computeIfPresent()` at the same time.  If `key` is not present, none will do `aggregate()`.  All five proceed to `computeIfAbsent()` and one of them will create a new entry, while the rest will do nothing.  I suggest (a) doing the 'absent' operation first, and (b) arrange for that to create a "zero" entry, which all threads (including the creator) can then call `aggregate()` *in any order*.  Or get the 'absent' operation to return a flag, saying "was absent".

Comment: @ChrisHall Exactly. As it stands, the code is not going to do what it was intended to do. I reversed the order of the statements but I can still see that the end result is not consistent.(Final aggregate result is not correct)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your understanding is correct. `computeIfAbsent()`/`computeIfPresent()` methods on `ConcurrentMap` do not employ locking. Instead, they work concurrently with other modifications.

Also note that the following is both non-thread-safe and bad practice:

```
private ConcurrentHashMap<String, MyPojo> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

You have to mark the field `final` if it will be accessed by other threads.

Also collections should be referenced by their interface:

```
private final ConcurrentMap<String, MyPojo> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```